# Check and align buffer

Tags: c, memory, alignment, buffer

I'm trying to understand how to check if a pointer is aligned or not and eventually align it.

To understand it I take this function:

```
#define PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT 8

PJ_DEF(pj_pool_t*) pj_pool_create_on_buf(const char *name,
                 void *buf,
                 pj_size_t size)
{
#if PJ_HAS_POOL_ALT_API == 0
struct creation_param param;
pj_size_t align_diff;

PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(buf && size, NULL);

if (!is_initialized) {
if (pool_buf_initialize() != PJ_SUCCESS)
    return NULL;
is_initialized = 1;
}

/* Check and align buffer */
align_diff = (pj_size_t)buf;
if (align_diff & (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1)) {
    align_diff &= (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1);
    buf = (void*) (((char*)buf) + align_diff);
    size -= align_diff;
}

param.stack_buf = buf;
param.size = size;
pj_thread_local_set(tls, &param);

return pj_pool_create_int(&stack_based_factory, name, size, 0, 
              pj_pool_factory_default_policy.callback);
#else
PJ_UNUSED_ARG(buf);
return pj_pool_create(NULL, name, size, size, NULL);
#endif
}
```

obviously the part that interests me is / * Check and align buffer * /
the only thing I think I understand is this:

let's focus on the if.
This wants to verify if the buffer is aligned to an 8 byte multiple address. If the condition of the if is not aligned, a number other than 0 returns, and then the alignment is carried out, otherwise, it is sufficient that there is also only a bit with a 1 to make the IF be skipped. To obtain this result they make the variable PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT a 7 (0111) and with this they make an AND with the address of where the buffer was allocated. The operation is as follows considering that I want to get a number other than 0 if the address is not aligned.

0000.. . 0111 AND

xxxx. . . x100

---

0000.. . 0100  **not aligned**

if there is a 1 (or more 1) in any of the last 3 bits and therefore I know it is not aligned with an 8byte block: x AND 1 = 0, the if will be true. then it will enter the correction block.

But the if block is obscure to me.
Someone who can confirm if my reasoning is correct and make me understand the block.

Comment: Basically aligning a block means to round up its start address to the next multiple of the alignment. For me this code looks strange. I would expect an extra line: `align_diff = PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-align_diff;` in the if block.

Comment: Your `align_diff` calculation needs correcting as suggested by @Gerhardh above. You could calculate `align_diff` in one statement, making use of 2's complement negation rules for unsigned types: `align_diff = (pj_size_t)(-(pj_size_t)buf) & (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1);`.

Comment: For clarification: Is this your code? Do you try to understand someone else's code or is this what you tried and you want to understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: It is not my code, it is the code of a project that is trying to study : https://www.pjsip.org/

Comment: I've emailed a bug report to the project mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current alignment code is incorrect. It determines the alignment difference from the lower alignment boundary and is incorrectly adding that to the pointer value to reach the upper alignment boundary:

```
xxxxx000 + 000 = xxxxx000 (OK - no change)
xxxxx001 + 001 = xxxxx010 (WRONG)
xxxxx010 + 010 = xxxxx100 (WRONG)
xxxxx011 + 011 = xxxxx110 (WRONG)
xxxxx100 + 100 = xxxxy000 (OK - rounded up)
xxxxx101 + 101 = xxxxy010 (WRONG)
xxxxx110 + 110 = xxxxy100 (WRONG)
xxxxx111 + 111 = xxxxy110 (WRONG)
```

The difference to the upper alignment boundary is the *2's complement* of the difference to the lower alignment boundary, modulo the alignment size:

```
xxxxx000 + 000 = xxxxx000 (OK - no change)
xxxxx001 + 111 = xxxxy000 (OK - rounded up)
xxxxx010 + 110 = xxxxy000 (OK - rounded up)
xxxxx011 + 101 = xxxxy000 (OK - rounded up)
xxxxx100 + 100 = xxxxy000 (OK - rounded up)
xxxxx101 + 011 = xxxxy000 (OK - rounded up)
xxxxx110 + 010 = xxxxy000 (OK - rounded up)
xxxxx111 + 001 = xxxxy000 (OK - rounded up)
```

The current alignment code can be corrected with the addition of a single line to convert the lower alignment difference to an upper alignment difference:

```
/* Check and align buffer */
align_diff = (pj_size_t)buf;
if (align_diff & (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1)) {
    align_diff &= (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1);
    align_diff = PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT - align_diff; // upper alignment
    buf = (void*) (((char*)buf) + align_diff);
    size -= align_diff;
}
```

Alternatively, the upper alignment difference could be determined directly before the `if`:

```
/* Check and align buffer */
align_diff = (pj_size_t)-(pj_size_t)buf & (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1);
if (align_diff != 0) {
    buf = (void*) (((char*)buf) + align_diff);
    size -= align_diff;
}
```

It could be argued (and has been!) that this is less readable than the original version.

In fact, the `if` could be omitted, since adding zero makes no difference:

```
/* Check and align buffer */
align_diff = (pj_size_t)-(pj_size_t)buf & (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1);
buf = (void*) (((char*)buf) + align_diff);
size -= align_diff;
```

Regarding `align_diff = (pj_size_t)-(pj_size_t)buf & (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1);`, the `(pj_size_t)buf` converts the pointer to an unsigned integer type, the `-` negates the value, and the initial `(pj_size_t)` converts the negated value to an unsigned integer type using 2's complement arithmetic. The `& (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1)` converts modulo `PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT` equivalently to `% PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT` (since `PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT` is a power of 2).

Strictly, to avoid *undefined behavior*, the above pointer to integer conversion should be done using `uintptr_t` (defined by `#include <stdint.h>`) instead of `pj_size_t`:

```
align_diff = (uintptr_t)-(uintptr_t)buf & (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1);
```

Regarding `buf = (void*) (((char*)buf) + align_diff);`, pointer arithmetic is not allowed on `void *` values (at least in standard C), so `(char*)buf` converts it to a pointer to `char`. Since `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte by definition, the `+ align_diff` advances the pointer by `align_diff` bytes as required.  The `(void*)` then converts this back to a `void *` before assigning that back to `buf`. This `(void*)` can be omitted in C (but not in C++), so the statement could be rewritten as:

```
buf = (char*)buf + align_diff;
```

which is arguably more readable.

Comment: I'll add `align_diff = (pj_size_t)-(pj_size_t)buf & (PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT-1);` to my "how to write C that your colleagues don't understand" guide. Thanks.

Comment: @4386427 Perhaps you should add it to your "How to impress and amaze my colleagues" guide. :)

Comment: nah, not impress... but rather in my "how to make sure your code is rejected in review" guide